# MySQL Select distinct column for each Relational_ID where largest timestamp below X

Tags: mysql, distinct

I am attempting to find all of the individual rows with a distinct or unique `In_Column` value for each `Item_ID` (our relational_id here) where `Item_Table` = 'X' and the `Timestamp` of the row is the highest for this distinct `In_Column` + `Item_ID` + `Item_Table` but lower than the supplied value.

**sample_table**

```
In_Column End_Value Item_Table Item_ID Timestamp
----------------------------------------------------------
Length    3         Pipe       3       2016-07-29 09:00:00
Length    2         Pipe       3       2016-07-30 09:00:00
Length    5         Pipe       4       2016-07-30 11:00:00
Kg        12        Pipe       3       2016-07-29 09:00:00
Kg        25        Steel      1       2016-07-29 09:00:00
```

**Ideal result if supplied date was current time and Item_Table = 'Pipe'**

```
In_Column End_Value Item_Table Item_ID Timestamp
----------------------------------------------------------
Length    2         Pipe       3       2016-07-30 09:00:00
Length    5         Pipe       4       2016-07-30 11:00:00
Kg        12        Pipe       3       2016-07-29 09:00:00
```

The ordering doesn't matter as I will be casting the return (which will be big, there is a lot of matching rows on the table) into an array following fetching.

Sorry for not providing an example query, I have played around with some concatenated LEFT JOINs but their execution time was understandably quite long and the result set wasn't as specific as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.*
FROM 
    `your_table` `t1`
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    `Item_ID`, 
                    `In_Column`,
                    MAX(`Timestamp`) AS `latest`
                FROM 
                    `your_table`
                WHERE 
                    `Item_Table` = 'Pipe' AND
                    `Timestamp` < 'Supplied Time'
                GROUP BY 
                    `Item_ID`, `In_Column`) `t2`
        ON 
            `t1`.`Item_ID` = `t2`.`Item_ID` AND 
            `t1`.`In_Column` = `t2`.`In_Column` AND
            `t1`.`Timestamp` = `t2`.`latest`
WHERE
    `Item_Table` = 'Pipe'
```

Just replace `your_table` with correct table name.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after! Cheers for the prompt reply, nice layout, and the extra effort of making a fiddle for it. So this is creating temporary tables of `your_table` with the alias t1, t2 then using these to match and draw the data from?

Comment: Something like that. When you use inner join from select then mysql creates some kind of temporary table.